# Any way to get sublime text to save settings files without running as sudo

Tags: installation, sudo, sublime-text

I installed Sublime Text 2 the following way, but what I do not like about it is that I have to run it as sudo to save the user settings files.  Any ways around this?

Thanks,

Colin

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time you ran sublime, you probably ran it as root. Thus on that first run your user settings where stored as 'root'. To change those permissions to your own do:

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername /home/yourusername/.config/sublime-text-2
```