# Sublime Text 2 not saving preferences

Tags: 12.04, sublime-text, preferences

I recently installed Sublime Text 2 on my Ubuntu 12.04. The problem is that whenever I open it, by default it opens up to two files: `sublime.desktop` and `defaults.list`. Also, whatever preferences I try to set aren't saved and I always get the default configuration (with these two files opened) every time I start it up. This wasn't the case with Sublime Text 1. It used to save my preferences and open on my last opened files. Why is this happening? How can I make it save my preferences as Sublime Text 1 did?

Comment: Try the answer given [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300326/any-way-to-get-sublime-text-to-save-settings-files-without-running-as-sudo)

Comment: ^Awesome! It works. I mean not exactly that, but a minor tweak of the same. Thanks

Comment: You can answer your own question ;-) please post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, when I first accessed Sublime Text, I accessed it as root, it's file permissions would need to be changed. It worked by the following command:

```
sudo chown -R username /home/username/.config/sublime-text-2/
```

in my case, it'll be:

```
sudo chown -R ranveer /home/ranveer/.config/sublime-text-2/
```

Thanks to the comments by @SylvainPineau